# Apache Pulsar schema validate with json string

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar

In my case, I have some raw JSON string data send to the topic and can't hard code POJO class, I want to use the pulsar schema feature to validate the structure. I have a topic "my-topic" and associated with JSON schema below, then I try to transmission some message.

```
var producer = client.newProducer(Schema.AUTO_PRODUCE_BYTES();
producer.send("{\"y\": 1}".getBytes()); // here! the value is 1(number) not string.

var reader = client.newReader(Schema.AUTO_CONSUME())
var message = reader.readNext();
I got {"y": 1}
```

my question is how pulsar schema works? The message should be rejected.

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "schemaInfo": {
    "name": "my-topic",
    "schema": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "Data",
      "namespace": "com.iot.test",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "y",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "JSON",
    "properties": {
      "__alwaysAllowNull": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my fault. just need to set

```
v2.5.0
bin/pulsar-admin namespaces set-is-allow-auto-update-schema --disable iot/test

v2.4.2
bin/pulsar-admin namespaces set-schema-autoupdate-strategy --disable iot/test
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Schema.AUTO_PRODUCE_BYTES` setting is useful for transferring data from a producer to a Pulsar topic that has a schema because it ensures that the sent message is compatible with the topic's schema. However, I don't see where you specified the schema for the topic.

A topic is assigned a schema automatically when you connect a typed producer or consumer, e.g.

```
Producer producer = client.newProducer(JSONSchema.of(SensorReading.class))
    .topic("sensor-data")
    .sendTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .create();
```

But you have stated that you cannot do this because you "can't hard code POJO". Therefore your only other option to assign a schema to the topic (so it can enforce message schema compatibility) is to use the [REST API calls](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/schema-manage/#schema-manual-management) for manual schema management.

Based on your schema, your schema-definition file would look something like the following:

```
{
  "type": "JSON",
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Data\",\"namespace\":\"com.iot.test\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"y\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}}",
  "properties": {}
}
```

HTH

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I have already specified schema by pulsar admin java API, my issue is the filed type of y is a string, but even if send int is work. `var producer = client.newProducer(Schema.AUTO_PRODUCE_BYTES();
producer.send("{\"y\": 1}".getBytes()); // here! the value is 1(number) not string.`

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command which shows the schema associated with the topic?  `pulsar-admin schemas get <topic-name>` ?